# How to use Bottom Nav View and AppBarLayout as an overlay and animate them in Android

Tags: android, overlay, bottomnavigationview, android-appbarlayout

I wanted to know how to use `Bottom Nav View` and `AppBarLayout` as an `overlay` and `animate` them (hide/show together on touch) just like apps like `Camscanner` do when viewing image? I want this behavior so that the canvas beneath it can use `fullscreen`.

**Update**

Note: This screenshot is from `Gallery Go` app by Google, it also hides the `ActionBar` and `BottomNavBar`.

[image]

**Update 2**

I used the `UiAutomatorViewer` to check the app's UI and found that it actually uses a `LinearLayout` with `ImageViews` for the `AppBar` and `TextViews` for the `Bottom Nav View`.

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of what you're trying to achieve? Please also tell us what have you tried.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati I'll edit my question and attach screenshot from Gallery Go, an app by Google, check it out :)